# How can I run clickhouse-local on ARM64

Tags: clickhouse

my operating system is：

```
Linux forlinx 4.4.189 #7 SMP Thu Nov 18 04:08:10 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

installed clickhouse-client from exist tgz, like this:

```
version: 22.9.3.18
tar -xzvf "clickhouse-common-static-$LATEST_VERSION-${ARCH}.tgz" \
  || tar -xzvf "clickhouse-common-static-$LATEST_VERSION.tgz"
sudo "clickhouse-common-static-$LATEST_VERSION/install/doinst.sh"

tar -xzvf "clickhouse-client-$LATEST_VERSION-${ARCH}.tgz" \
  || tar -xzvf "clickhouse-client-$LATEST_VERSION.tgz"
sudo "clickhouse-client-$LATEST_VERSION/install/doinst.sh"
```

then do my query:

```
clickhouse-local -S "id Int64" -N "tmp_table" -q "CREATE TABLE if not exists test_batch (id Int64,EventTime Date) ENGINE = MergeTree() PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(EventTime) ORDER BY id;INSERT INTO TABLE test_batch values(1,'2021-05-05');" --logger.console  --path /tmp/local
```

```
2022.10.24 14:51:16.166465 [ 6193 ] {} <Error> bool DB::(anonymous namespace)::checkPermissionsImpl(): Code: 412. DB::Exception: Can't receive Netlink response: error -2. (NETLINK_ERROR), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):

0. DB::Exception::Exception(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, bool) @ 0x6d51948 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
1. ? @ 0x6d7fcfc in /usr/bin/clickhouse
2. ? @ 0x6d7fee8 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
3. DB::TaskStatsInfoGetter::TaskStatsInfoGetter() @ 0x6d7f6d4 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
4. ? @ 0x6d7f494 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
5. DB::TaskStatsInfoGetter::checkPermissions() @ 0x6d7f424 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
6. DB::TasksStatsCounters::create(unsigned long) @ 0x6d783f0 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
7. DB::ThreadStatus::initPerformanceCounters() @ 0x103c5604 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
8. DB::ThreadStatus::setupState(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::ThreadGroupStatus> const&) @ 0x103c5264 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
9. DB::CurrentThread::initializeQuery() @ 0x103c79a4 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
10. DB::BackgroundSchedulePool::attachToThreadGroup() @ 0xf5e9ee0 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
11. DB::BackgroundSchedulePool::threadFunction() @ 0xf5ea064 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
12. ? @ 0xf5eb0d8 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
13. ThreadPoolImpl<std::__1::thread>::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<std::__1::thread, void*>) @ 0x6de5680 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
14. ? @ 0x6dea8c4 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
 (version 22.9.3.18 (official build))
```

at the same time, 以上步骤在AMD64的Ubuntu系统是可以work的.
can someone help

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your ARM server does not have IPv6 support, but you have configured clickhouse-server to listen to the address :: which is an IPv6 wildcard address.

You can replace :: with 0.0.0.0 for IPv4.

Look details
https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/41601#issuecomment-1253173925